# RESTful partial updates for resources with read-only elements?

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm designing a RESTful API that currently has resources that include some elements that can be updated by clients and others that can't.  As an example:

```
{
    id : "1234",
    firstName  : "George",
    lastName   : "Burdell",

    blogPosts : { href : "http://server.com/user/1234/blogposts"}
}
```

A client of the API can PUT a new resource or PATCH an existing resource, but in the example they could only write to `firstName` and `lastName`.  `id` and `blogPosts` are generated by the server and are not modifiable by the client.

What's the recommended way to handle an attempt to write to a non-writable field?  Return 401 and ignore the entire update document?  Is 401 the appropriate response?

Is having a resource that includes both writable and non-writable elements a bad idea?  (I'm new at this, but it seems that it may often be unavoidable, especially in cases like the example when linked to related resources).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a 403 and don't update the resource.

> **403 Forbidden**
>
> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
>   the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
>   why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
>   for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make
>   this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) can be used instead.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want them to have the ability to write to the JSON object, I wouldn't make it available to them, thus throwing an error if they did try to write to it.